# Select multiple items from drop down (without repetition) and sum their values from a lookup

Tags: excel, vba

In sheet **`Input Variable`**, I have a cell **`F3`** containing *[multiple items selected from a drop down (without repetition)](https://trumpexcel.com/select-multiple-items-drop-down-list-excel/) and separated with comma.*

[image: drop down]

Their *lookup values* are in another sheet **`Ref Data`** as shown below:

[image: ref data]

I would like to get their sum in cell **`G3`**.

```
=VLOOKUP(F3,'Ref Data'!B:C,2,FALSE)
```

So far I am getting value for only one item.

For example:

[image: one item]

But when I select another item from the drop down, I am getting **`#N/A`** value

For example:

For items **`Delivery, Pilot`**, value should have been **`1500`** *(1000 + 500)*

[image: multiple item]

***How may I resolve this issue ?***

EDIT:

```
Function Mult_Lookup_and_Sum(strCommaSepInput As String, _
                                rngLookat As Excel.Range, _
                                lngSumCol As Long) As Double

Dim a() As String
Dim lngCounter As Long

a = Split(strCommaSepInput, ",")

Mult_Lookup_and_Sum = 0

For lngCounter = 0 To UBound(a)
    Mult_Lookup_and_Sum = Mult_Lookup_and_Sum + _
                Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup( _
                    Trim(a(lngCounter)), rngLookat, lngSumCol)

Next lngCounter

Erase a

End Function
```

Upon using the above function as mentioned in answer by

```
=Mult_Lookup_and_Sum(worksheets("Input Variable").range("f5"),worksheets("Ref Data").range("B:C"),2)
```

I got this error:

[image]

Upon examining bit further:

[image]

Comment: I suggest to make a userform with a ListBox where the user can multiselect the items and which writes then the concatenated string and the sum into the sheet.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Can you be kind enough to explain it in detail ?? I have very limited knowledge of excel and vba, unfortunately.

Comment: Sorry that is a way too broad to give as an answer. It was just an idea that this might be easier.

Comment: Can you just help me with the issue I am facing ?? Is there any excel function that I can use ??

Comment: Well on every change of the value in the cell with the drop down you would need to `vlookup` the item that was newly added in your table with the costs you would need to lookup the costs for that item and add them to the cell right next to it like `Target.Offset(0,1).Value = Target.Offset(0,1).Value + LookedUpCosts`.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ One thing more Sir, how may I define `LookedUpCosts` ??

Comment: Have a look at the [WorksheetFunction.VLookup method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.vlookup). You need eg. lookup for `Pilot` in your cost table to get it's cost.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function like so.

```
    Function Mult_Lookup_and_Sum(strCommaSepInput As String, _
                                rngLookat As Excel.Range, _
                                lngSumCol As Long) As Double

Dim a() As String
Dim lngCounter As Long
Dim dblAdd As Double

a = Split(strCommaSepInput, ",")

Mult_Lookup_and_Sum = 0

For lngCounter = 0 To UBound(a)
    dblAdd = 0
    On Error Resume Next
    dblAdd = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup( _
                    Trim(a(lngCounter)), rngLookat, lngSumCol, 0)
    On Error GoTo 0
    Mult_Lookup_and_Sum = Mult_Lookup_and_Sum + _
                dblAdd

Next lngCounter

Erase a

End Function
```

I have `test 1,test 2` in A1 and in D1:E2 I have Test 1 total and Test 2's total.

So I would call like so `Mult_Lookup_and_Sum(range("a1"), range("d1:e2"),2)` the last argument is the same as the column number's function in `vlookup`

Comment: In my case, the lookup values are in sheet `Ref Data`. How may I call this function ? I have tried doing `Mult_Lookup_and_Sum(range(F5), range('Ref Data'!B:C),2)` and `Mult_Lookup_and_Sum(range("F5"), range("'Ref Data'!B:C"),2)` but it doesn't work

Comment: Also, Is `Dim a() As String Dim lngCounter As Long` correct ?? Shouldn't it be `Dim a As String Dim lngCounter As Long` ??

Comment: No, cause `a` is an array `()` means it's empty, `a(100)` for example would create `a` with space for 100 entries.  Get the answer working first, then question the code. :o)

Comment: `Mult_Lookup_and_Sum(range("f5"), worksheets("Ref Data").range("b:c"),2)` is not working :(

Comment: Apologies for questioning the code. Actually when I pasted your code into the VBA editor, it gave me red line over that line. So I asked you.

Comment: What's the error, you need to give me more than just keep saying things like not working.  I cant see your screen, nor your data etc.

Comment: `Mult_Lookup_and_Sum(worksheets("sheet1").range("a1"),worksheets("sheet2").range("A:B"),2)` works for me.

Comment: Please see the updated question, I have added a screenshot

Comment: Ah, I thought you were calling by VBA.

Comment: `=Mult_Lookup_and_Sum(A1,Sheet2!A1:B2,2)` works for me.

Comment: `=Mult_Lookup_and_Sum(F5, 'Ref Data'!B:C, 2)` not working for me :(

Comment: again, I cant see your data, nor what is in F5.  You need to do some investigation yourself.  It works fine in VBA and from a Worksheet call for me.  Added a space in the sheet name also, just in case, but `=Mult_Lookup_and_Sum(A2,'Sheet 2'!$A:$B,2)` works also.

Comment: I've changed the function a little, try this version.

Comment: I have tried new version of code. But it's not working still. And `F5` has the same comma separated values like `F3`. I have tried to apply the above version of code on `F3` with `=Mult_Lookup_and_Sum(F3, 'Ref Data'!B:C, 2)` but again it didn't work.

Comment: That is what I coded off and tested against, so I cant offer you anymore help.  Start to do some work yourself, look at what is happening in the code.  Are they all `,` separated?  https://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s196/step-through-code.htm